# Add an incremential number to each feature in a FeatureCollection in GEE

Tags: python, javascript, google-earth-engine, features

Bit stuck at the moment on this. I need to add an incremental number (1:total length) to each feature in a FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine.

So consider for instance the GAUL dataset as example. How would I add each of these newids to the dataset (one unique id per feature) ?

```
dataset = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")
newid = ee.List( list(range(1,dataset.size().getInfo() )) )
```

I can map a function to add a field, but this in itself needs to be mapped over the newid list I imagine?

```
def addField(feature, id):
  return feature.set({'sum': id})
dataset = dataset.map(addField, id)
```

Happy for any hints in javascript or python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing these kind of things - creating lists of collections - is typically not a good idea. But if you really need to, I suppose you cold do like this:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/460a24fc7139d2cedafb72a052ab4fef

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")
var indexes = ee.List(dataset.aggregate_array('system:index'))
var ids = ee.List.sequence(1, indexes.size())
var idByIndex = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(indexes, ids)
var datasetWithId = dataset.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.set('id', idByIndex.get(feature.get('system:index')))
})
print(datasetWithId.first().get('id'))
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I forgot the system:index column exists ;)