# Add a computed list as a property to each feature of a featurecollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm computing a reducer over a featurecollection using reduceRegions. I would like to add back the computed properties as a "sum" property to each feature of the initial featureCollection.

As I don't have access to the index when running map or iterate, I fail to see how to merge to two structures together.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
var list = ee.List([1, 0, 1])
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([geometry, geometry2, geometry3])
var total = fc //do something here
```

total should look like

```
{
    feature1: {geometry: geometry1, sum: 1},
    feature1: {geometry: geometry2, sum: 0},
    feature1: {geometry: geometry3, sum: 1},
}
```

Set is obviously not working as it's setting metadata of the featurecollection and not the underlying features. I've thied the following functional approach:

```py
def add_property(name, list_fc, list_prop, prop):
  index  = list_prop.indexOf(prop)
  feat = list_fc.get(index)
  return ee.Feature(feat).set(name, prop).copyProperties(feat)
```

But it's failing when two properties have the same value (I get the wrong index). What should I do ?

Comment: When you use `ee.Image.reduceRegions` using a `ee.FeatureCollection`, you get a new `ee.FeatureCollection` with the properties of the original feature collection + the result(s) of the reducer. Isn't this already what you want in this case? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reversing the problem. The main issue when aggregating a FeatureCollection and a List is that the feature collection don't provide a numbered index to merge the to entity. `system:index` can be anything as long as it's unique but it's never is a nice numbering from 0 to `size()`.

So what I decided to do is add an index to my FeatureCollection following this: [Add an incremential number to each feature in a FeatureCollection in GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374137/add-an-incremential-number-to-each-feature-in-a-featurecollection-in-gee). and then map the collection itself to create the feature (As I can now use get("id") th retreive the position of the feature.

Here is a small example:

```js
// load the data 
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")

// add an Id column to the featureCollection indexed from 0
var indexes = dataset.aggregate_array('system:index')
var ids = ee.List.sequence(0, indexes.size().subtract(1))
var idByIndex = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(indexes, ids)
var dataset = dataset.map(function (feature) {return feature.set('id', idByIndex.get(feature.get('system:index')))})

// load some random data 
var values = ee.List(ids.map(function(i){ return ee.Number(i).multiply(2)}))

// add them as property to each feature of the collection 
dataset = dataset.map(
  function(feat){
    return feat.set("sum", values.get(feat.get("id")))
  })
print(dataset.first())
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/42ea30a34b778bf5ec32057050ff4822

PS: I'm pretty sure it's not the best way to answer but it solved my urgent issue. I'll let anyone smater than me come with a better anwer, I'll validate it.